# html_checkboxes Smarty

Tags: php, html, smarty

I work with form using Smarty.
There are some validation to check the phone number and email using regular expression.
And if it's all correct, users can jump into the confirmation page, otherwise these checks shuold be remained.
I use checkboxes_html with some option "selected".
But all checks I made are gone if the validation doesn't succeed.

[php]

```
// Lists for the radio button
$smarty->assign('genre_output', array('apple','chiken','tuna'));
$smarty->assign('genre_values', array('apple','chiken','tuna'));
```

[html]

```
<tr>
<th>Genre</th>
<td>
{html_checkboxes name="genre" values=$genre_values output=$genre_output selected="{$data['genre']|escape}" separator='<br />'}
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Show how you validate in PHP and repopulate data to form.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It works for me:

tpl file:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   {html_checkboxes name="genre" values=$genre_values output=$genre_output selected=$genre_selected separator=""}
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

php file:

```
$smarty->assign('genre_output', array('apple','chiken','tuna'));
$smarty->assign('genre_values', array('apple','chiken','tuna'));
$smarty->assign('genre_selected', $_POST['genre']);
```